# Creating Story Map based on image keywords?

Tags: arcgis-online, story-map

I would like to create an interactive map that displays photos based in their geotags but could also be sorted by other metadata components like keywords. The keywords are mainly based on species, so ideally the user can click on the species and view their distribution within the map.

I think I am looking for a layout similar to [Esri's Crowdsource Story Map](https://esrioceans.maps.arcgis.com/apps/StoryMapCrowdsource/index.html?appid=f531139be54345eabfcc127ba21455cf) .

If not Story Map, I am open to other mapping platforms.